# Error with gcc installing psutil (and it's dependants) with pip

Tags: linux, python, redhat-enterprise-linux, gcc, pip

I'm trying to install Apache Airflow, using pip. In the process of doing that, it tries to install psutil, and gets a gcc error. If I try to install psutil separately, it still gets the same error.

```
pip install psutil


Collecting psutil
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/ca/5b8c1fe032a458c2c4bcbe509d1401dca9dda35c7fc46b36bb81c2834740/psutil-5.6.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: psutil
  Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4on5rz85/psutil/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-i327xkin-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_memory_leaks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_linux' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=563 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/psutil/_psutil_common.o
    psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4on5rz85/psutil/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-i327xkin-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4on5rz85/psutil/
```

I know it says "No such file or directory" about psutil, but I don't seem to guess how to have that directory if I'm trying to install it.

I've already tried with pip, pip3, and python3 -m pip, to the same message.

I've already installed python-devel and openssl-devel (from some recommendations from the net).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Specs: gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 , Red Hat 7.7

Comment: »» Python.h: No such file «« : Install `python-devel python3-devel`

Comment: @KnudLarsen `python-devel` is already installed and in the latest version available (python-devel-2.7.5-86.0.1). And I have no package python3-devel available in Oracle or EPEL repository (the ones I'm currently using).

Comment: Oracle Enterprise tends to be a little different from the original Redhat RHEL. ( Oracle EL´s are Redhat clones.) .... You can get default packages from the free version = 'Redhat CentOS 7.7' :  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.7.1908/

Comment: @KnudLarsen thanks for your help. I finally ended up installing CentOS repository, and then deleting the version I had por python3-devel and installing again (it was more advanced that the one I needed, for some reason, but installing from CentOS repo did the trick with the version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@KnudLarsen](https://superuser.com/users/525523/knud-larsen) for the help. This is what did the trick for me, in case anyone has the same problem.

I installed the CentOS repository. I tried downloading the python3-devel package from there, but there was a problem with the dependencies, specifically with python3 and python3-libs, which I had in version python3-3.6.8-10.0.1 and python3-libs-3.6.8-10.0.1, and needed version python3-3.6.8-10 and python3-libs-3.6.8-10.

So I removed those packages (and the dependencies they had), and tried to install them again (actually, just installing python3-devel was enough). It installed the correct version, and from there the pip command for installing psutil or apache-airflow worked like a charm.

PD: I found somewhere that I had to update the gcc version for it to work. I didn't need it, but if what I did didn't work for you, hypothetically reader, try with that.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Enterprise tends to be a little different from the original Redhat RHEL. ( Oracle EL´s are Redhat clones.)

You can get default packages from the free version = 'Redhat CentOS 7.7' :

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.7.1908/